# Run-time Error '9'. Sub-script out of range error in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a

> Run-time Error '9' : Sub-script out of range.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistributeRows()

Dim a As Variant, h As String
Dim i As Long, nr As Long
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
  a = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
  Set rng = .Range("M2:M" & UBound(a, 1))
End With

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

  For Each c In rng
    If c <> "" Then
      If Not .Exists(c.Value) Then
        .Add c.Value, c.Value
      End If
    End If
  Next
  v = Application.Transpose(Array(.keys))
End With

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
  h = v(i, 1)
    If Not WorksheetExists(h) Then
      Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = h
      Sheets(h).Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a, 2)).Value
    End If

Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
        h = a(i, 3)
        nr = Sheets(h).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Sheets(h).Range("A" & nr).Resize(, 3).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
        Sheets(h).Columns.AutoFit
Next i

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

I'm getting the error on this line.

`nr = Sheets(h).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`

The excel sheet I'm trying to pull it from has information like this

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPqzO.jpg).

Dropbox file related to the error

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64819855/StackOverflow.xlsx

The goal of this script is to create new tabs in the worksheet based on the "Current Location (Column M)". I have multiple current locations (maybe 100+).
Then it would copy all the data relating to Column M. E.g. everything in Los Angeles, would be copied to the Los Angeles Tab.

Thanks.

Comment: Guessing `sheets(h)` is faulty...

Comment: What is the value of h when it stops?  does it equal the name of one of your sheets

Comment: you are using `v` to create the named sheets but then `a` to access them. Maybe the data in `v` and `a` doesn't mesh properly.

Comment: It stays on the last sheet. (which is Vancouver)

For example, if I use some other column, it works ok - sometimes.

Comment: It would be nice if you used better variables XD Code so hard to follow ;_;

Comment: You do a Worksheet Exists test in the portion right above that, why not do another Worksheet Exists test when you change the value of `h` again.

Comment: Haha, I'm trying! I'm sort of new to VBA (learned it all from homeandlearn.org) so I'm still getting a grasp on this.

I didn't think I would need one because it works for other columns; so I'm confused on what's causing the current location to flop.

Comment: The 1st error is looking for "Price-1" worksheet, it does not exist... so the "Sub-script is out of range"

Comment: Davesexcel - Thanks for your help! I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code and understood what the problem was. Here's the updated code and if you guys ever need to do something similar - hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistributeRows()

Dim a As Variant, h As String
Dim i As Long, nr As Long
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

//Change Range("XX#:X" to whatever you want to create new tabs from.

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
      a = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
      Set rng = .Range("M2:M" & UBound(a, 1))
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

      For Each c In rng
        If c <> "" Then
          If Not .Exists(c.Value) Then
            .Add c.Value, c.Value
          End If
        End If
      Next
      v = Application.Transpose(Array(.keys))
    End With

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
      h = v(i, 1)
        If Not WorksheetExists(h) Then
          Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = h
          Sheets(h).Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a, 2)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(a, 2)).Value
        End If

    Next i
        For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
            h = a(i, 13)
            nr = Sheets(h).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            Sheets(h).Range("A" & nr).Resize(, 16).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 16).Value
            Sheets(h).Columns.AutoFit
    Next i
    // Change the Resize(, XX) to whatever you want to copy until.
    // Also change the H = a(i,XX) to whatever column your "tab names" are at.
    // 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```